# Firebase Functions with CircleCI integration

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, circleci

In a basic Firebase Functions project, the package.json file is being created in the functions folder. Now we're going to use CircleCI for our project. To getting this CI to work, the package.json needs to be in the top folder of your repo and not in any other subfolder as seen in this post here: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/cant-run-npm-install/19012

Now if I move the file to the root and correcting all the paths, I'm able to build and to use lint on the project, but the deploy is failing with the error, that firebase has got no directory path of the project. It looks like there is a hard coded method in firebase-tools which is preventing the moving of the package.json outside of the functions folder.

If I duplicate the package.json and put it back into the functions folder, everything is working fine but this is not a solution.

**Here is my desired structure:**

```
myproject
 |
 +- .firebaserc
 +- firebase.json
 +- package.json
 +- tsconfig.json
 +- tslint.json
 |
 +- functions/
      |
      +- src/
      |   |
      |   +- index.ts
      |
      +- lib/
          |
          +- index.js
          +- index.js.map
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "functions/lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "./functions/lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "./functions/src"
  ]
}
```

Does anybody has already tried Firebase Functions with CircleCI or has any clue how to get this to work?

Comment: Can't you get CircleCI to effectively `cd functions` before running npm commands?  I don't think you'll be able to move package.json, because `functions` is effectively the root of the node app you're working with, and package.json must be at the root of the node app.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that moving the file is not an option. You are right @Doug, I will try this and post it as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I got this thing up and running. You need to specify the working directory for every command in CircleCI to be exactly `~/project/functions`. Now CircleCI is finding the package.json file.

This is our **config.yml** for CircleCI:

```
version: 2
jobs:
    build:
        docker:
            # specify the version you desire here
            - image: circleci/node:6.14


        steps:
            - checkout

            # Download and cache dependencies
            - restore_cache:
                keys:
                    - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "./functions/package.json" }}
                    # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
                    - v1-dependencies-

            # Install all needed dependencies from package.json
            - run: 
                working_directory: ~/project/functions
                command: yarn install

            # Save the cache including node_modules folder
            - save_cache:
                paths:
                    - ~/project/functions/node_modules
                key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "./functions/package.json" }}

            # Create the folder for your unit test results
            - run: 
                working_directory: ~/project/functions
                command: mkdir junit

            # run tests with mocha!
            - run:
                working_directory: ~/project/functions
                command: yarn test_ci
                environment:
                    MOCHA_FILE: junit/test-results.xml
                when: always

            - store_test_results:
                path: ~/project/functions/junit

            - store_artifacts:
                path: ~/project/functions/junit
```

And the **package.json** with extra command `test_ci` for unit testing on CircleCI:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha --require ts-node/register ./src/test/*.spec.ts",
    "test_ci": "mocha --require ts-node/register --reporter mocha-junit-reporter ./src/test/*.spec.ts"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.13.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.6.0",
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^0.17.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^4.3.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^3.18.0",
    "mocha": "^5.1.1",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.17.0",
    "sinon": "^4.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```